# Is there a way to force wrapped text to be right justified?

Tags: html, css

I have a column header where there is very limited horizontal space.

But I can afford a bit of vertical space so I've enabled wrapping.

My question is this: is there a way for me to force the wrapped text to be right-justified rather than left-justified.

In other words... it's wrapping like this:

```
Model
Validation
```

But I would prefer it to wrap more like this:

```
.....Model 
Validation
```

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

Answer (score 4):

I believe `text-align: right` should fix this

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, the `text-align` property is the key.

```css
p {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p>Extraordinary Terminology is Key!</p>
```